# Variables with zero variation in time series random forest estimation

Tags: time-series, forecasting, random-forest

I am trying to build a forecasting model for three products. Because I have only 20 -25 daily readings per product sales and these series have gaps during the time span of analysis, I switched to the cumulated yearly sales series.

By using them, I am trying to forecast next year's sales figure. In that sense, my whole estimation process changes to cross-sectional exercise.

However, I have some macro variables such as "inflation", "consumer confidence" etc... for three years.  Because my all variables are in a yearly aggregated state, and I have limited data to convert my project to a panel time series model, I only have zero variance economic variables. Such as a variable for 2015's inflation, a variable for 2016's inflation or 2017's inflation. Do you have any suggestion to add these economic variables to my data's current structure?

Comment: there are several concurrent themes in your question. Suggest to narrow down the focus. The question title suggests `zero deviation` whereas the question body mentions `zero variance`. Please see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and learn how to ask a good question.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use a predictor `inflation` and insert the 2015 value for your 2015 observation, the 2016 value for your 2016 observation and so forth.

Of course, you will need to *forecast* inflation itself to include it in your model. If you can do that reliably enough to improve your sales forecast, I assume banks and governmental agencies will be far more interested in this aspect than your current employer. (Meaning: I don't think inflation will improve your forecast.)